# Config android studio for offline not working

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin

I need to use android studio at work, but the proxy doesn't let me download the packages, so I try to use android studio in offline mode following this tutorial:

https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/studio-config#offline

So I completed the steps, and created a project. I activated 'offline work' in the Android Studio->settings->gradle, but when I try to build it, android studio still tries to download gradle. I also get an error when syncing: Unknown host 'services.gradle.org'. You may need to adjust the proxy settings in Gradle.

btw the 2 zip files for maven and gradle each contain one folder. do I need to extract these folders or their content into the manual-offline-m2 folder? I assume the latter but I tried both and it didn't work

Comment: Have you set the compiler to work offline?

Comment: @TaseerAhmad How do it?

Comment: once you sync online than you work offline on Gradle.

Comment: Forever? For all new projects?

Comment: Yes, always you sync first than work offline.